# Removing EXPLICIT asymmetry in open set intersection vs. union axioms in topology.

Tags: general-topology, axioms

Firstly, I want to emphasise that I understand why the open set version of the axioms of topology require that only only the finite intersection of open sets is guaranteed to be open. I know some standard demonstrations of this necessity, like that on the real line $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^+, (-1/n, 1/n)$ is open but $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}^+} (-1/n, 1/n) = \{0\}$ which is not open. This is not what my question is about.

However, I have never been pleased with the asymmetry between the axioms for intersection and union, I have always found it kinda ugly and inelegant. The worst presentations explicitly invoke indexing by natural numbers, but the neatest versions I've seen are still asymmetric, saying that the intersection of two open sets is open, but union of arbitrary open sets is open.

My question is whether there is an alternate axiomatisation of topology via open sets (potentially radically different) which is aesthetically "nicer" in this regard, which removes the explicit asymmetry while still being logically equivalent.

I am familiar with other axiomatisations of topology which do not use open sets at all, such as the neighborhood definition or the Kuratowski closure axioms. While these are interesting, they are not what this question is about (although do share if you think you have a really strange and interesting formalism).

Comment: A certain degree of asymmetry is inevitably needed, see [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19152/why-is-a-topology-made-up-of-open-sets/19156#19156) for a reason.

Comment: Topology (formerly Analysis Situs, i.e. positional analysis) was initially about metric spaces, and  a nbhd of $x$ wa just a set that covered  an open ball centered at $x ,$ of positive radius. These are $interesting$ sets. It is a $corollary $  of this def'n that  if $V$ is a non-empty family of nbhds of $x$ then $\cup V$ is a nbhd of $x$ and that if $V$ is finite then  $\cap V$ is a nbhd of $x$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet That has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 3):

An Alexdrandov space is a topological space for which the
intersection of any collection of open sets is open.

A $T_1$ Alexdrandov space is discrete.
That is what happens when the axioms are made symmetrical.
A bunch of low level spaces not fit for analysis,

Comment: Please read the question body.

Comment: @user6873235.  No, Alexandrov spaces are not logically equivalent to topological spaces and there is no way of making them so.

Comment: Yes, I know, which is why it doesn't answer the question. I was asking if there was a way to remove the EXPLICIT asymmetry by choosing a different set of axioms (and thus having it remain implicitly as a theorem of these new axioms), rather than just weakening the old axioms.

Comment: @user6873235.  The question has been answered no.   Take a look at pointless topology.  Only sober (I kid you not) spaces can be pointless.  Pointless topology is a pointless attempt of category theory to define topology.  Forthcoming will be symmetrical topology?   Will it preserve topology's duality?

Comment: What are you going on about? I never brought up pointless topology. I am not trying to express topology with category theory or anything like that. I am not asking to drop the logical requirement that only finite intersections of open sets are guaranteed open. I am only looking for some alternate (BUT EQUIVALENT) axiomatisation of open sets which does not have this explicit asymmetry between intersections and unions (potentially never mentioning them at all), but from which this asymmetry is a derivable property of open sets. In short, to make the explicit asymmetry, implicit.

Comment: Simply similarity @user6873235 with the abstract nonsense of catagory theory.  Let us know if you make any progress with symmetric  topology.  I consider it a fruitless endeavour.

Comment: For god's sake, I'm not trying to create a new version of topology, I'm just looking for a different (EQUIVALENT) axiomatisation which is a little nicer. There's already other axiom sets which define topology in terms of neighborhoods, closed sets, closure axioms etc which are all equivalent, but have a radically different flavour. I think that looking for a slightly different but equivalent method for describing open sets is a pretty conservative ask in comparison to defining topology with, say, the Kuratowski closure axioms.

Comment: Go for it! @user6873235